# Hardware acceleration FFMPEG not speeding up rendering at the moment

Tags: ffmpeg, hardware-acceleration

I currently have ffmpeg running on a computer (ubuntu server 20.04) with a nvidia MSI GTX 1660 6GB GAMING X TWIN FORZ 7 GRAPHICS CARD and a Ryzen 5 3600 cpu. I have installed the nvidia drivers for linux for it.

Currently when enabling and disabling hardware acceleration the rendering takes the same amount of time which is around 1 minute to render per 1 minute of footage.

When using a similar setup in davinci resolve it takes 1/4 of the time to apply similar background effects and concating the clips which makes me question if I am using hardware acceleration of if my ffmpeg command is not optimised for it?

This is the code which takes in around 50 mp4 clips and joins them together, scales them in size and applies a background blur on the sides of clips

```
ffmpeg  -hwaccel cuda  -f concat -safe 0 -i /home/anon/project/MEDIAFILES/work_ffmpeg_space/concat_file_user_root_projectId_1.txt  -s 1920x1080 -filter_complex '[0:v]scale=ih*16/9:-1:flags=bicubic,boxblur=luma_radius=min(h\,w)/20:luma_power=2:chroma_radius=min(cw\,ch)/20:chroma_power=1[bg];[bg][0:v]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2,crop=h=iw*9/16' -af aselect=concatdec_select,aresample=async=1  /home/anon/project/MEDIAFILES/created_videos/finalvideo_user_root_projectId_1.mp4
```

Any tips or ways to optimise the code to use hardware acceleration will be greatly appreciated!

This is my ffmpeg configuration

```
  ffmpeg version N-103221-gc3ef9e0277 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)
  configuration: --pkg-config-flags=--static --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvpx --enable-libopus --enable-opencl --enable-libxcb --enable-opengl --enable-nvenc --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-ffplay --enable-ffprobe --enable-libxvid --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-openal --enable-openssl --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-cuvid --extra-cflags=-I/usr/lcal/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 --extra-libs=-lpthread
  libavutil      57.  3.100 / 57.  3.100
  libavcodec     59.  4.101 / 59.  4.101
  libavformat    59.  4.101 / 59.  4.101
  libavdevice    59.  0.100 / 59.  0.100
  libavfilter     8.  1.103 /  8.  1.103
  libswscale      6.  0.100 /  6.  0.100
  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libpostproc    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
```

Comment: You did not specify a hardware accelerated encoder so it automatically chose libx264 which uses the CPU. Secondly, you are using CPU filters. Start at [FFmpeg Wiki: Hardware Acceleration](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro) and https://superuser.com/a/1296511

Comment: @llogan thanks for those links, so to fix that would I need to add "encoder=h264_nvenc" to enable the gpu encoder and then is there a way to convert the cpu filters to gpu filters or does it have to be rewritten?